# react redux reducer adding object to array in object

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am working on a react redux app. I have state object like

```
const initialState = {
  articles: []
};
```

each item in 'articles' is like

```
{
    id:1,
    data:'data'
}
```

I need to add another object to the array without removing the existing objects in the array.

I tried

```
return {...state,articles: [...state.articles] };
```

in my reducer but it ends up removing the existing items.

what should it be so that it does not remove existing items?

Comment: Please provide the code before the `return`. I'm curious with your statement `it ends up removing the existing items.`. If this is true, it's like saying `state.articles` is mutated.

Answer (score 0):

In Reducer return using `immutable update pattern`

`return { ...state, articles: action.payload.data };`
for more information on [reducer immutable pattern](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns).

Answer (score 0):

You should spread your current articles into a new array as you did, and append the payload from your action.

```
return { ...state, articles:  [...state.articles, payload] }
```

An example of how your action should look:

```
export function addArticle(article) {
    return { type: "ADD_ARTICLE", payload: { article } };
}
```